# iF Then Else code - how to make this run faster? VBA

Tags: performance, vba, if-statement

I have a simple code which takes a long time to run. I was wondering if there is any way to make this run faster? Maybe this part (Cells(i, "U").Value = Cells(n, "X").Value) should not be used 2 times! Thanks!

```
For n = 3 To time_frame + 3
For i = 3 To 1002

If (Cells(i, "U").Value = Cells(n, "X").Value) And (Bed_in_use < 24) And Wait_L > 0 Then
Wait_L = Wait_L - (24 - Bed_in_use)
ElseIf (Cells(i, "U").Value = Cells(n, "X").Value) And (Bed_in_use < 24) And Wait_L <= 0 Then
Bed_in_use = Bed_in_use + 1
End If
Next i
Next n

MsgBox "The number of bed in use is " & Bed_in_use & ". There are " & Wait_L & " patients in the waiting list."

 End Sub
```

Comment: You could create an array of the values in rows "U" and "X" then compare the values of the array rather then the cells.

Comment: @jcarroll OK could you please let me know how I can create array of the value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what your code is trying to do. But here is a sample of how you would compare two lists, and keep track of the total matches.

```
Sub test()

    Dim arrayU() As Variant
    Dim arrayX() As Variant

    Dim LrowU As Integer
    Dim LrowX As Integer

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim bed_in_use As Integer

    LrowU = Columns(21).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LrowX = Columns(24).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ReDim arrayU(1 To LrowU)
    ReDim arrayX(1 To LrowX)

    For i = 1 To LrowU
        arrayU(i) = Cells(i, 21)
    Next i

    i = 1

    For i = 1 To LrowX
        arrayX(i) = Cells(i, 24)
    Next i

    i = 1
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To LrowX
        For j = 1 To LrowU
            If arrayX(i) = arrayU(j) Then bed_in_use = bed_in_use + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    MsgBox (bed_in_use)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple things will speed this up - The first was mentioned in the comments by @jcarroll, pulling the cells you need into an array and using that instead of making repeated calls to `Cells`.

The second is what you mentioned, structuring your `If` statements in a way that 
you aren't making the same comparisons twice. For example, this has to be true for *either* condition...

```
Cells(i, "U").Value = Cells(n, "X").Value
```

...and this *always* has to be true:

```
Bed_in_use < 24
```

After `Bed_in_use` is 24 (or higher), you can exit out of the loop because you'll never satisfy either the `If` or the `ElseIf` statement.  I'd re-roll it into something like this:

```
Dim values() As Variant
values = ActiveSheet.UsedRange  '...or whatever Range you need.

For n = 3 To time_frame + 3
    If Bed_in_use >= 24 Then Exit For
    For i = 3 To 1002
        If Bed_in_use >= 24 Then Exit For
        If values(i, 21).Value = values(n, 24).Value Then
            If Wait_L > 0 Then
                Wait_L = Wait_L - (24 - Bed_in_use)
            Else
                Bed_in_use = Bed_in_use + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next n
```

Comment: It is great! But how about use "go to the line ..." instead of using "then exit for" ? Then I can add statment for Bed_in_use < 24?

Comment: @Hamidkh - I wouldn't use a goto.  If you need to replace `Bed_in_use < 24`, just replace it with either a different condition or a function call.